# How do I wirelessly connect to a computer using python

Tags: python, sockets, connect, wireless

I am wondering if there is any way to wirelessly connect to a computer/server using python's socket library. The dir(socket) brought up a lot of stuff and I wanted help sorting it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear of what you mean by "Connect to a computer" so I gave you a TCP socket server and client.
Create a socket server on the computer you wish to "connect to" with:

```
import SocketServer
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    server.serve_forever()
```

Now create the client:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

(SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(data + "\n")

    received = sock.recv(1024)
finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

You run the server and then the client and the server should receive the client's connection and send it whatever you have as the data variable on the server. Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as it was very explanatory, but one question. Is the socket server specific to python, or can another language host and python connect or vise-versa?

Comment: I believe python can host and another program can connect, yes. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

> but one question. Is the socket server specific to python, or can
>   another language host and python connect or vise-versa?

As long as you are using `sockets` - you can connect to any socket-based server (made with any language). And vice-versa: any socket-based client will be able to connect to your server. Moreover it's cross-platform: socket-based client from any OS can connect to any socket-based server (from any OS).

Comment: EXTREMELY helpful. Thank you.